# Redux: Is it wrong, this all-around action creator pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a newbie. I'm not sure, is using below the pattern wrong/silly?

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from "redux-actions";

const CHANGE_STATE = "appState/CHANGE_STATE";

export const changeState = createAction(CHANGE_STATE, (key, val) => ({ [key]: val }));

const initialState = {
    maxBodySize: 1920,
    isMaxBody: true,
    isMobile: false
};

export default handleActions(
    {
        [CHANGE_STATE]: (state, { payload: changedState }) => {
            const newState = {
                ...state,
                ...changedState
            };
            return newState;
        }
    },
    initialState
);
```

Only one `actionCreator` editable every state. Like this:

```
// Can editable every state with 'changeState' action.
appState.changeState("isMaxBody", true);
appState.changeState("isMobile", true);
appState.changeState("maxBodySize", 960);
```

Can I continue to use this handy pattern?

If this pattern is bad, give some instructions to me, please.

Comment: Please, add your code to the question, instead of images.

Comment: @MatheusReis Ok, I did.

Comment: By the naming of `createAction`, I would assume you still have to dispatch right? `dispatch(appState.changeState(…))`?

Comment: @Li357 Right!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I continue to use this handy pattern

I don't see why you "couldn't". It seems perfectly valid, in a strict sense.

As for whether or not it's a good idea, well, that's open to opinion, but I would not recommend using this pattern. Here's a few reasons:

- You lose the abstraction between "actions" and "state modification". It's nice to be able to say "perform this action", and not have to worry about what the actual state changes are. Some actions may modify multiple parts of state. All of that is abstracted away from you, making it more controlled and testable. In a similar vein, this probably won't work well with, say, middleware, for similar reasons.
- Modifying string properties "looks icky", and generally seems error prone. You'll get no help from tooling if you accidentally put a typo in a property name somewhere in your app.
- Similar to the above, you lose any ability to leverage static typing (flow or TypeScript, for instance). Having written a decently large React/Redux app in a team, I highly recommend using something like TypeScript, and this pattern will not work well in a strongly/statically typed app.

Those are my opinions, derived from my experience. If the pattern works well for you and what you are trying to accomplish, you might find that it's just fine.

P.S. if you are going to use a pattern like this, I don't see why you wouldn't just do e.g. `appState.changeState({isMaxBody: true});` instead of `appState.changeState("isMaxBody", true);`. It seems a little cleaner, and at least closer to allowing better typing.

Comment: Your suggestion is good for me. I'd better use this pattern for the simple switch on/off. Thx!!!